# Magento 2 Change the email address of store when customer places order

Tags: magento2, order-email, sales

how to change the email address where we get the email when an order is placed on our magento 2. I want to add the multiple email address where email should be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set email address store wise. You need to swich store and fill email address.

Please check below URL
https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-change-store-email-addresses-magento-2.html
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Buddy. I was doing the same but it still wasn't working because I was changing it in the different store view.

Comment: what you want explain with screenshot!